# How can I view disassembly of a JITted method in a .NET program when attaching to it with WinDbg?

Tags: c#, .net, windbg, jit, disassembly

Similar to [this question asking the same but in VS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423547/how-can-i-view-the-disassembly-of-optimised-jitted-net-code), I'd like to ask how can I use WinDbg to view diassembly of a JITted method?

Breaking this into two parts, in both cases there's the same `SomeNamespace.SomeClass.Foo()` method that I want to disassemble.

1. We only have the executable `program.exe`, and want to run it via WinDbg's `Open Executable`.
2. There's an already running process in which I want to inspect the same JITted method. (Say that we can't control how the process gets started)

Now from my understanding, JIT runs the first time a method is called. If this is true, in `2.` it might be the case that the method wasn't JITted yet. Is there a way to force the JIT to run on the method in that case, so that we can inspect the result?

**TL;DR: How do I disassemble a JITted method with WinDbg?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know a way of forcing the JIT compilation of a method, but [sosex](/questions/tagged/sosex)' command `!sosex.mbp` (set managed breakpoint) also works when the method has not been jitted yet and it will break as soon as it was JIT-compiled.

After that, the [SOS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb190764(v=vs.110).aspx) commands `!ip2md`, `!dumpil` and `!u` may be helpful. If you know the JITted code address, you can also do a native `u` on it.

As mentioned by [@Steve Johnson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1269097/steve-johnson), author of SOSEX, in the comments, SOSEX also has commands `!mu` ("managed unassemble") and `!muf` ("managed unassemble function") that can help with already JITted functions.

Comment: The question is ambiguous. The title and the tl;dr ask about disassembling a jitted method, but the core of your question asks about forcing jit on a non-jitted method. For a method that HAS been jitted, use !sosex.mu and !sosex.muf, on !sos.u. If the method has NOT been jitted, use Thomas' method.

Answer (score 1):

You can force JIT compilation by calling [PrepareMethod](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zbcd4yfw(v=vs.110).aspx)

You can view disassembly with `u` command in WinDbg and SOS. See example [here](https://dpaoliello.wordpress.com/2012/02/05/getting-the-disassembly-and-il-for-a-jittedngened-net-method-using-windbg-and-sos-dll/).

Finally, maybe you can try [DumpMiner](https://github.com/dudikeleti/DumpMiner). This UI tool, let you view disassembly of jitted method without knowing how to use WinDbg